# Do the pairing axiom, subset axiom and union axiom imply replacement axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying Set theory from Daniel Cunningham's textbook. This is how Cunningham states replacement axiom:

Let $\psi (x,y)$ be a formula. For every set $A$, if for each $x\in A$, there is a unique $y$ such that $\psi (x,y)$, then there is a a set $S$ that consists of all the elements $y$ such that $\psi(x,y)$ for some $x\in A$.

Suppose that we assume the hypothesis of the previous axiom. Then for each $x\in A $, there is a unique $y$ such that $\psi (x,y)$ holds. Then $P_{x}=\{ x, y \}$ is a set by the pairing axiom. Then $C=\bigcup \{ P_x : x \in A \}$ is a set by union axiom. Then $C\setminus A$ is the set $S$ that is provided by the replacement axiom (obviously we assume the subset axiom).

So, is the replacement axiom really needed or am I incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your argument, you are forming the set
$$
\{ P_x : x \in A\}.
$$
To prove that this set exists (i.e., a set such that for each $x \in A$ there is a unique element in the set of the form $\{x, y\}$ where $\psi(x, y)$ holds) you need the replacement axiom, in general.